# Update controller scope from ng-includes / ng-repeats

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a basic question regarding angular scopes (which probably was answered before, but i cant find a solution):

In my app views are multiple ng-includes with other angular-elements which create sub-scopes, (e.g. ng-repeats) in them. I want to managed them all in one controller, but in the ng-include templates, I have to use $parent.variable_name, to access/change variables from the controller. Inside a ng-repeat inside a ng-include, I have to use $parent.$parent.variable_name to access/change it. That gets confusing realy fast, as its hard to tell, how deep you sub-scopes are.

Is there a better way to reference the controllers variables and functions inside the subviews?

Comment: The best way to share data between controllers is using a service/factory.

Comment: You could use directives!

Comment: how can I do this, when I´m only using one controller? I have one main controller - no subcontrollers for ng-include, ng-repeat etc. 
Sorry, I´m a bit new to angular

Comment: do you use ui-router in your app?

Comment: if you use ui-router you can define multi ng-view in your app, also you can define [1] app with [n] submodule.

Comment: jup, I´m using ui-router. But I don´t want to have more controllers if possible (already using a lot). My Problem is more, that I have a controller for a given view, inside that view I have some ng-includes, inside them some ng-repeats.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service/factory (service/factory are singleton).

```
angular.module('moduleName')
  .factory('factoryName', function() {
    return {
      variableName: 1
    };
  });
```

Then go in your controller (you can use it in all your other controllers) and use the factory.

```
angular.module('moduleName')
  .controller('controllerName', function($scope, factoryName) {
    $scope.data = factoryName;
  });
```

Then in your HTML you can simply bind it.

```
<div ng-controller="controllerName">
  {{ data.variableName }}
</div>
```

Didn't test it tho. but it should work :)

Comment: so with this approach (and your example), I have to set ng-controller for each ng-include and ng-repeat to the "controllerName"?

Comment: i guess you're having a subcontroller (or more subcontrollers). just use the factory in your subcontrollers and youll have access to that variable. do you have a sample code?

Comment: no smaple code right know, if you like I could make a jsfiddle, but that would take a while. Imagine I have one controller "mainCtrl", which handles a part of the view. in this view, there are two forms, both of them included via ng-include. Now "mainCtrl" should get the ng-models from the forms, but I have to refernece them with $parent.$parent.modelname...

Comment: I think giving those ng-include a controller would be fine. and then sharing those data via a service.